# how to implement checkall via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have many checkbox and a separate checkbox. i will when user click on separate checkbox, other checkboxes select or deselect.
For this purpose i use following javascript file, but doesn't work good. it sometimes work and sometimes not.
whats is its problem.
Thanks.

```
function toggle() {
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (isChecked == true) {
        isChecked = false;
        selectCount = 0;
    } else {
        isChecked = true;
    }
    for ( var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (isChecked)
                selectCount++;
            c[i].checked = isChecked;
        }
    }
    if (isChecked)
        selectCount--;
}
```

I use selectCount for another purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NSu8x/2/))

```
var chk = document.getElementById('all');
chk.onchange = function(){
    var all = document.getElementById('checkall').children;
    var status = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i].checked = status;
    }
}
```

Or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/NSu8x/3/) (using inline `onchange` event)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="all" type="checkbox" name="all" onchange="toggle(this)" />Toggle
<div id="checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" />One
    <input type="checkbox" />Two
    <input type="checkbox" />Three
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function toggle(el){
    var all = document.getElementById('checkall').children;
    var status = el.checked ? 1 : 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i].checked = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RasoulTaheri, You are welcome, BTW, next time you ask an answer, please include `HTML` too, it may help to understand the problem with current code :-)